# UIButton in iOS 7 translucent and round like Phone App

Tags: ios7, uibutton, uikit, core-graphics

In iOS 7, the Phone dialling app has a round translucent rim and tapping on the button you can see a blurred version of the wallpaper you've set.

Is there a standard way of making such translucent rimmed buttons that blur the background only around the rim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that there is **not** a standard way to do this. There are however several techniques that can be used to achieve this blur effect.

Essentially, every `drawRect:`, you want to capture the background, blur it and adjust the saturation and brightness, and then mask it to the circle border.

If you want the entire button to be blurred when pressed, you could check for that state in the button and then adjust the mask to include the whole button and maybe reverse the text so that it is still readable.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunate - I felt this probably was the case. It's a lovely effect but seems like it's not simple to achieve.